# Fortune tellers have dinner

Tags: word, wordplay, knowledge, crossword-clues

*I've seen these before somewhere (maybe here?), but they're all mixed up!*

**Who/what is being described by the clues below?**

> Consequence of a disastrous harvest
>   What a mathematician might do to clarify their work
>   Result from removing belly hairs
>   Criminal who upgrades photography equipment
>   Lobbying requests from a vessel
>   Murders with a knife
>   Fun name for a keyboard app
>   One way to complete a visual arts project
>   Be afraid of the 10th
>   Milwaukee team fan’s collection, maybe
>   Agent 47, for example
>   Like a debatable point
>   Label on a Soviet trash can, perhaps
>   Casual greeting to a parental unit

---

**HINT 1**

> This person also smashes their mouth against a wall and hires a doggo.

**HINT 2**

> Once you've solved the clues, you need to do something with them in order to extract a final clue that gives the final answer. You can do the same with the title clue to get the common theme among all these clues. Perhaps you should *bother a male sheep* about it?

**HINT 3**

> For the first four clues, the enumerations are (4 3), (4 5), (5 3), and (6 6 4).

Comment: are all the clues referring to the same object?

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Not really, but they are all related by a category, which the final answer is also a part of

Comment: any letter count clues please? +1

Comment: Pretty sure PiIsNot3 would have put them in if they were meant to be part of the puzzle.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Patience, I'll include some as a hint if no headway is made :)

Comment: OK, so I *may* have underclued this one a bit from usual... I've added a bit of flavortext that may or may not be useful, and if still no progress is made, I'll add letter counts.

Comment: Has a correct answer been given? If so, please don't forget to $\color{green}{\checkmark \small\text{Accept}}$ it.  If not, some responses to the answerers to help steer them in the right direction would be helpful.

Answer (score 19):

The flavour text says that we're looking for something we've seen before "here". On this site?

Hint 2 says we should

> "bother a male sheep" (nag a ram), so the solution involves changing the order of letters.

The title

> "Fortune tellers have dinner" resolves to "seers sup" which in turn anagrams to "PSE users".

The method, then is to

> solve the crossword clue, then anagram the solution into the name of a Puzzling user. There is one extra letter in each case.

Solving the clues:

> *Consequence of a disastrous harvest* (4 3)
>  none fed = noedne + F
>
>  *What a mathematician might do to clarify their work* (4 5)
>  hone axiom = hexomino + A
>
>  *Result from removing belly hairs* (5 3)
>  sleek gut = El-Guest + K
>
>  *Criminal who upgrades photography equipment* (6 6 4)
>  camera change thug = Gareth McCaughan + E
>
>  *Lobbying requests from a vessel*
>  rowboat petitions = TwoBitOperation + S
>
>  *Murders with a knife*
>  stabs = Bass + T
>
>  *Fun name for a keyboard app*
>  my pocket organ = Omega Krypton + C
>
>  *One way to complete a visual arts project*
>  use video = Deusovi + E
>
>  *Be afraid of the 10th*
>  fear J = jafe + R
>
>  *Milwaukee team fan’s collection, maybe*
>  antler hoard = Rand al'Thor + E
>
>  *Agent 47, for example*
>  hitman = athin + M
>
>  *Like a debatable point*
>  moot = Tom + O
>
>  *Label on a Soviet trash can, perhaps*
>  our bin = Rubio + N
>
>  *Casual greeting to a parental unit*
>  hey mom = M Oehm + Y

The extra letters spell

> FAKESTCEREMONY

The final answer is

> phoniest rite = PiIsNotThree, i.e., OP's former username

Hint 1

> wham tooth = HowToMath
>  appoint woofer = PowerOfAPoint
>  which are two other aliases listed in OP's profile

Comment: That's ingenious. I was really hoping that the second-to-last would be rot13(UVFGBEL), though, and that doesn't seem to fit the pattern. (And there aren't obvious sheep-botherings for most of them -- but maybe that happens later.)

Comment: You got the mechanism correct! And at this point, I can confidently say that I should've included the letter counts in the original formulation of this puzzle, considering that the category you identified, while interesting and certainly fitting, is not what I'm looking for. I'll include the letter counts in another hint.

Comment: I will say, though, that a couple of those answers come *really* close to the intended answers, so don't scrap them just yet!

Comment: Personally, a debatable point is rot13(zbbg).

Comment: @Tom Thanks! I had my mind set on "issue" for some reason...

Comment: As said in the second clue, the title also hints at the theme: rot13(frref fhc -> CFR hfref)

Comment: 5&14) rot13(Ebjobng crgvgvbaf -> GjbOvgBcrengvba + F  & Url zbz -> Z Bruz + L)

Comment: @Tom Thanks! The extra letters look like they could spell something like rot13(???rfg (p)re(r)zb(a)l)...?

Comment: Would it be feasible that a mathematician might want to rot13(ubar nkvbz)?

Comment: @hexomino Ooh, that would make sense. Thanks!

Comment: 10) maybe rot13(nagyre ubneq -> Enaq + r) as the team [logo](https://www.nba.com/bucks/history/logo) shows these.

Comment: 1) rot13(abar srq) - we should've got this one first!

Comment: @Tom Aaaa of course!

Comment: I'll make this a wiki since it's a group effort.

Comment: Unsure of the wiki-etiquette so have made my edit to resolve the final two outstanding clues: 7) rot13(zl cbpxrg ncc) and 13) rot(n ynory ba n Fbivrg genfu pna - orvat fbzrguvat funerq ol gur pbzzhar - jbhyq or 'bhe ova')

Comment: I have a feeling the final result is different from the intermediate results. also, rot13(cubavrfg naq fgrcura funer n ybg bs yrggref)

Comment: @user39583 Ahh, of course! Well done figuring out the last step. Would you mind creating a separate answer for the purpose of awarding the bounty? Any idea about how to interpret hint #1?

Comment: @jafe I don't feel like I really deserve the bounty. Added my guess for hint 1.

Comment: @user39583 Well, you answered the exact question I was looking an answer for when I set the bounty, so I disagree :P Hint 1 looks very plausible as well!

Comment: @jafe Ok, posted the final steps as a separate answer!

Answer (score 5):

At jafe's request, I'm posting my contributions as a separate answer. Most of the puzzle was solved by other users.

The final answer is

> phoniest rite = PiIsNotThree, i.e., OP's former username

Hint 1

> wham tooth = HowToMath
>  appoint woofer = PowerOfAPoint
>  which are two other aliases listed in OP's profile

Comment: Thanks! I'll award the bounty tomorrow when the system allows me to.

Comment: You know what, this is the first time I have ever realised that the first 4 letters of that username were 'PI IS' and not 'PILS'. This might explain why none of my pings ever worked for them! (facepalm) Good thing for me they made their name much simpler :D

Comment: @Stiv I was about to comment exactly the same. Always made me think of beer. Pi Is makes far more sense!

Answer (score 2):

**Partial**

Agent 47 for example

> Hitman (as in the game)

The common theme might refer to

> Computer games/programs, or professions?

Casual greeting to a parental unit

> Yoda (YO+DA) if the common theme is just characters?

Random thoughts that don't seem to fit any common theme, some don't quite fit the clues:
Consequence of a disastrous harvest

> Famine/Hunger?

Murders with a knife

> Stabs (or Stabbings if 'murders' is a noun rather than a verb)

Like an unnecessary point

> Needles / Needless

Label on a Soviet trash can, perhaps

> Red ... litter? (pun on red letter, bit of a stretch)

Comment: Two of your answers are correct, but not the category. Keep trying! :)